# How do I remove sap that has oozed out of a board?

Tags: finishing, sap

I have a Douglas Fir post that I want to use on a project. Since I bought it a couple of years ago, drops of sap have oozed out of it and now cover the surface. What is the best way to remove these?

Comment: My initial search didn't locate that question, but it does answer my question. Thanks, Matt.